# Is there a difference in docker-compose up --build vs. docker-compose build && docker-compose up

Tags: docker, docker-compose

We were trying to build and run docker-compose project on remote host. I tried using:

```
docker-compose -H 'ssh://remote_address' up --build
```

And got

```
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
```

So we tried:

```
docker-compose -H 'ssh://remote_address' build
docker-compose -H 'ssh://remote_address' up
```

Which worked fine. My problem is I can't find evidence in docs for this to be correct behaviour. Is this a bug in docker-compose, a feature, or a bug in my environment?

Comment: I'd guess this to be a bug in Compose, and would follow up via [its GitHub repo](https://github.com/docker/compose).

Answer (score 10):

I'm not sure of the error you got for the first command, I mean `docker-compose -H 'ssh://ip' up --build` as it may be really a but, but the three mentioned commands have surely differences. I'll try to explain in my simple way:

1. First command is `docker-compose up --build`.

This command finds `docker-compose` file and rebuilds the image then make it running. Suppose you have made some changes into your `docker-compose` file, so when you only run `docker-compose`, you'll get a warning that image is not rebuilt, you should run `docker-compose up --build` to rebuild it and make everything be built again (despite something done before and present in cache).

2. Second command is `docker-compose build`.

This command only **builds** your image based on `docker-compose`, but does not **run** it. You can see the built image by `docker image ls` or `docker images`. Also executing `docker ps -a` should not see your recent built image running.

3. Third and the last command is `docker-compose up`.

If this command is entered for the first time, it tries to run everything in `Dockerfile` if exists and download base image, etc. Then makes the image and runs the container.

If the image has been built before, it just runs it.

Unlike the first command, the third one only runs the latest build of that image, but would not build it again.

Comment: Thanks for explanation, however my problem lies in `-H` flag interpretation. It appears that `docker-compose up --build` ignores it and tries to connect to default docker engine on `unix:///var/run/docker.sock` which is unavailable in my environment.

Comment: I've read the manual of docker for `-H`, and it seems the socket on Host server (in your case, your remote ssh server) should be running. If I've understood it correctly, have you checked if docker is running in remote server?

Comment: As I wrote in question remote Docker Engine is running and everything works as expected when I use `docker-compose -H 'ssh://remote_host' build && docker-compose -H 'ssh://remote_host' up` instead of `docker-compose -H 'ssh://remote_host' up --build`